# Select only ids from table A that don't have multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

table a

```
id | food
1  | rice
2  | rice
3  | rice
4  | rice
1  |  beans
```

My results should only be ids (2 ,3 and 4) with the food type. I don't want id 1 because it has 2 different records. Help?

Comment: this is not a way to question here

Comment: so... something like... `select * from table where food_id in (select id from table group by food_id having count(food_id)=1)`  there's actually a few ways you could write that.  you could join in the nested query instead of using it in the where.  you could do a not in, too.

Comment: select distinct id, list agg.............
from ( select id food_category where id not in (select id, food from food_category where food = 'beans' and food = 'rice') group by id)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Also, please incorporate the information needed in the question rather than trying to use a screen dump.  The information needed is a table name, the relevant columns and types, and some sample data (you already indicate the required output).  You should show what you've tried and what it produces and explain why it's wrong.  With SQL questions, it is usually a good idea to specify the DBMS you are using — the relevant answer often varies between different DBMS, though in this case it is pretty much DBMS-neutral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,

Assuming that your expected output is:

3,4 -> you could try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM tableA
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) = 1
```

This will select all ids from the table that occur only once